# Mysql query optimize

Tags: mysql

I have two tables "Category" table having one of columns as "category name" and "Professional" tables, having one of column as "category id".

Now I am searching for certain categories in "Category table", then getting those professionals that have that category.

The problem that I am facing is that in case of joining "Professional" and "category" table its looking as if too many rows in "Professional" table are being searched. (Ignore if I am wrong)

Is it possible that join only happens on those rows that have been returned from search in "Category" table.
[image]

```
explain select c.id from professional_categories as c  
inner join professionals as p  on p.professional_category_id=c.id 
where c.professional_category_name like 'ABC%'
```

Below are the indexes from professional table.
[image]

Comment: Show indexes from p table

Comment: Look, you need to once again go through the query, since there isnt any of its column which you are adding in the where clause, if still you dont find any, you can try with
`YOUR QUERY AND p.id>0`

Comment: Have you tried it with `ORDER BY category_id` on `professionals`? Besides no index is applied on `category_id` in `professionals`-table and `ORDER BY` facilitates sparse index. I think you may try that.

Comment: @SashiKant : didn't get you ? Do you mean that the where clause should have columns indexed in professional table ?. BTW adding p.id>0 reduced rows to ~8500

Comment: @viv : And also You should try with creating an index on `p.professional_category_id`
Show us the explain plan after adding the index

Comment: @RajeshPaul : Are you saying this : EXPLAIN SELECT p.id
FROM professionals AS p
INNER JOIN professional_categories AS c ON p.professional_category_id = c.id
WHERE c.professional_category_name LIKE  'T%'
ORDER BY p.professional_category_id  , not much difference in this.

Comment: @viv isn't it making any difference in the no of rows checked?

Comment: If not then you should try making an index on `professional_category_id` in `professionals`table

Comment: @RajeshPaul : No much difference, they were around 17400

Comment: @SashiKant : Bang !! You got it, that reduced rows to 81, I think it worked.

Comment: @RajeshPaul : Looks like that worked, sashi also advised that, thanks to both of you, count is now 81 :)

Comment: @SashiKant You can post an answer now, I will accept it

Comment: @RajeshPaul You can post it as an answer, since I first saw sashi one, I will have to accept that, but I will +1 to your answer. Thanks again

Comment: I am not here for points, good that it helped you

Comment: @viv thanx for your consideration. Fair enough.

Comment: @SashiKant : great........... keep going

Comment: @viv: :-)
Here for only learning... :-)

Comment: @viv Your qustion is a great demonstration of the utility of `index` in a database. Hence it deserves a +1 from me.

Comment: @RajeshPaul : Thanks, I was not able to figure out that this was happening due to index. There are guys out here like sashi and on opposie side there are some, who will not help, but if didn't understood what you are saying, then -1 :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an **`index`** on `professional_category_id` in **`professionals`** table.

This will facilitate **faster and minimal searching** of the records.

### Alternative

This problem could also be solved using **referential integrity** constraint as follows:

If the **professional** table had the attribute **professional_category_id** as a **foreign key** referencing to the **category_name** attribute in the **category** table then also this could be achieved. This **foreign key constrint** also facilitates **faster/minimal** search. In this case you don't need to **explicitly** create any **index** on the **professional_category_id** attribute